# Create a special matrix with data from two lists in R

Tags: r

i have here a minimal sample data to understand my final matrix:

```
test <- list( c(1, 2, 3, 4) )
test2 <- list( c(2, 3) )
```

and my matrix should be:

```
2 4 6 8
3 6 9 12
```

it's like a nestes for loop. I go over each row and in each i use the value from it and sum it with column value.

after a few houres I have this:

```
sapply(2, function(j) lapply(seq_along(test), function(i) test[[i]] * test2[[i]][j]))
```

it gives the final simulated row two: (param for row is '2' after sapply)

```
[[1]]
[1]  3  6  9 12
```

The going over rows could be done with seq_along(test2) but i don't know how to save data after each row ... i was last testing this: .. and fail..

```
a=matrix(data=0, nrow=2, ncol=4)
lapply(seq_along(test2), function(k) a[k,]<-unlist(sapply(2, function(j) lapply(seq_along(test), function(i) test[[i]] * test2[[i]][j])) ) )
```

output:

```
[1]  3  6  9 12
```

---

Later on, i would like to have more vectors in input lists and repeat the hole action descriped on top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `outer` after `unlist`ing the `list`

```
t(outer(unlist(test), unlist(test2)))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    2    4    6    8
#[2,]    3    6    9   12
```

Comment: working - i'm said because i search so long and didn't use a standart useage ;)

Answer (score 1):

You mean matrix multiplication? Quick example:

```
> t(matrix(unlist(test)) %*% matrix(unlist(test2), nrow = 1))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    2    4    6    8
[2,]    3    6    9   12
```

Comment: i will check this now